Is it worth it to use the Transcendent Embryo to try and get the last few Chaos blessings for their Minor Prophecy?
I only need 2 more Chaos blessings to complete the Minor Prophecy for getting all of them, but Giving Up my Nights don't seem to change the options much.
Sometimes it changes, but sometimes it doesn't.
Is the possibilities each Night restricted to a subset of what's possible, so that once I see X number of Chaos blessings, then I've seen all the possibilities that night and have to try again another Night?

Given that the likely last Boon you're wanting is Chant, it's not worth it, because it needs Aether first, which only comes from Duo Boons, and the game likely won't break that rule for the Embyro.
Meaning it's best to pick a Keepsake that guarantees a starter Boon of a god you want, that's not Hermes, since he doesn't have Duo Boons. I'd advise Poseidon for the chance of getting extra Gold, and the Boons that do that can be a Duo with Hera or Demeter.

You can confirm that yourself by looking at the code, if I could pin down where to look, but I can't.
SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Hades II\Content\Scripts's KeepsakeData calls Chaos's Keepsake "RandomBlessingKeepsake"...
"TraitData_Keepsake.lua" is where all the Keepsake info is stored, or at least enough to have search terms like "TransformBlessing".
It'd probably be better to just get a Duo Boon ASAP and search rooms carefully for Chaos Gates, even though they're hard to find in the Fields of Mourning and possibly don't appear in Tartarus.
That is, in-place of switching to the Embryo from a Force[God]BoonKeepsake after Hecate and hope for random Chant.
